# the operation is not valid for the state of the transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server

Below is the code and i am getting error on opening of connection.The connection state when this is executed is closed.

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                cmd.CommandText = CommandName;
                //cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars);
                if (pars != null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(pars);
                }

                try
                {
                    **if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }**

                    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Don't close and re-open connections

Comment: What is the exact text of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all in your IF Condition.

Your IF statement might be true even when ***ConnectionState*** is ***broken***, because it is not equal to ***open***.

Then it will go and try to open the connection, but it is already open and is broken. So, it would not be able to open it again.

Just get rid of that IF condition and try executing it.

Comment: `IF` loop?! That's a conditional, not a loop.

Comment: thanks for reply ... so do i need to open the connection and close it again or not ?

In between i got this error too, but it was once only.

The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction. TryOpenConnection at offset 16 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0